# Error in code TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python

```
from sklearn import tree
import numpy as np

#data=vadi,samvadi,pakad
X=np.array[[8,3,[5,7,10,8,7,8,5,7,3,2,5,7]],[12,7,[5,7,8,11,12,8,10,7,5,7,3,5,2,0]],[8,1,[4,5,8,8,7,5,7,4,5,1,1,0]],[5,0,[4,5,7,8,12,8,10,8,7,5,1,1,0]],[5,0,[5,3,0,1,0,8,10,12]],[5,0,[5,3,5,8,10,8,5,3,0]],[4,11,[7,6,7,4,5,4,0]],[9,2,[9,4,2,7,7,9,5,2,0,2,-3,0]],[5,0,[-3,-1,0,5,9,10,9,5,5,7,9,3,5,3,2,0]],[7,2,[2,7,5,7,3,2,5,5,7]],[9,4,[0,2,0,4,5,11,9]],[4,11,[-1,2,4,2,7,2,-1,2,0]],[4,11,[10,7,4,5,4]],[4,11,[10,9,5,7,9,5,4,7,5,4,2,0]],[9,4,[12,11,9,11,9,6,4,6,9,11,12,13,12]],[5,0,[0,5,7,9,11,13,11,9,5,7,4,1,0]],[4,11,[-1,0,1,4,1,4,1,5,4,6,4,1,0]],[7,0,[-1,1,4,6,7,8,7,6,4,6,1,4,1,0]],[7,0,[-1,0,6,3,6,7,6,3,6,3,1,0]],[8,3,[8,7,6,3,1,3,1,0]]]

#classification
Y=np.array['asawari','asawari','bhairav','bhairav','bhairavi','bhairavi','bilawal','bilawal','kafi','kafi','kalyan','kalyan','khamaj','khamaj','marwa','marwa','pooravi','pooravi','todi','todi']

#decision tree classifier
clf=tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

#trending data
clf=clf.fit(X,Y)

#predict
prediction=clf.predict(8,3,[5,7,10,8,7,8,5,7,3,2,5,7])

print prediction
```

But I am getting this error

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Which line causes the exception? Pls post the full trace back.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `np.array` because it is a function. `a[b]` means "the b<sup>th</sup> item of a", which isn't what you want.

Replace `np.array[...]` with `np.array([...])`.